# Where are all the missing methods of AngularJS deferred?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jquery-deferred, deferred

I am using AngularJS and working with deferrers and promises. There are a lot of methods missing in the AngularJS deferrers and promises. For example:

1. In angular, how can I get the promise status? In jQuery I can do:

   ```
   $.deferred().status();
   ```
2. In order to create resolved deferred, I have to write two lines of code:

   ```
   var d = $q.defer();
   d.resolve();
   ```

   Where in jQuery it takes one line:

   ```
   $.deferred().resolve()
   ```

There are many other issues I encounter during development. Am I missing something?

Comment: In your second example, `var d = $q.defer(); d.resolve();` is syntactically identical to `$q.defer().resolve()`, so I'm not sure what the problem is.

Comment: @rossipedia: This specific is not a problem since I can achieve the same in AngularJS, but AngularJS required two lines. There are more other issues like the first issue I mentioned and I will update the question when I'll found another annoying issue.

Comment: What I'm saying is that your example #2 is false. Angular doesn't require two lines, as you can just call `$q.defer().resolve()`.

Comment: @rossipedia: Of course I can but if I'll do var d = $q.defer().resolve(); d will be undefined!